# Errors processing thinkfan package any time I try to install or run an upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, compiz, acer

I'm having problems when installing compiz manager , and other software from ppas or by using the command line, this is what I get, I don't know if someone can help me with this. It's driving me mad.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10

```
angelo@angelo-Aspire-E1-430:~$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
compiz-plugins is already the newest version (1:0.9.13.0+16.10.20160818.2-0ubuntu2).
compizconfig-settings-manager is already the newest version (1:0.9.13.0+16.10.20160818.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up thinkfan (0.9.2-1) ...
Job for thinkfan.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status thinkfan.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript thinkfan, action "start" failed.
● thinkfan.service - simple and lightweight fan control program
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar 2017-01-24 03:00:52 CST; 29ms ago
  Process: 7100 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan (code=exited, status=4)

ene 24 03:00:52 angelo-Aspire-E1-430 systemd[1]: Starting simple and lightwe....
ene 24 03:00:52 angelo-Aspire-E1-430 thinkfan[7100]: thinkfan 0.9.1 starting...
ene 24 03:00:52 angelo-Aspire-E1-430 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Control p...4
ene 24 03:00:52 angelo-Aspire-E1-430 systemd[1]: Failed to start simple and ....
ene 24 03:00:52 angelo-Aspire-E1-430 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Unit ente....
ene 24 03:00:52 angelo-Aspire-E1-430 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Failed wi....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package thinkfan (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1


Errors were encountered while processing:
 thinkfan
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just solved it , if someone is having the same problem , its related to thinkfan , a software, just run:

`sudo apt-get remove thinkfan`

and everything will work as before !!

Comment: The correct use of `thinkfan` is detailed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481459/thinkfan-control-doesnt-use-the-fan-full-potential-when-needed