# Unable to get fan to work on Lenovo 14w

Tags: lenovo, fan, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my new Lenovo 14w laptop and I noticed that the fans are not running at all, causing high temps.

I have installed `fancontrol` but couldn't figure out the config.

Running `pwmconfig` results in an error `There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

And lastly, `sensors-detect` shows I have `AMD Family 15h thermal sensors (driver 'k10temp')`

Some posts seem to mention that some Lenovo models have their fans controlled by the UEFI BIOS, however there aren't any such options in my BIOS.

What can I do to get the fan spinning?

Edit: [Here's the full `sensors-detect` output](https://pastebin.com/870ifCaZ). Couldn't fit in this post due to character limit

Comment: post the full output of `sensors-detect`

Comment: @rtaft added full output

Comment: I don't think fancontrol is going to work, I'm not seeing anything you can use with pwm.  `thinkfan` might be the way to go, I don't have any experience with that.  Does `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` exist?

Comment: @rtaft `/proc/acpi/ibm` folder does not exist

Comment: Does it exist after installing `thinkfan`?  What is in `/proc/acpi`?  thinkfan is acpi based instead of pwm.

Comment: @rtaft `/proc/acpi/` contents do not change after installing and running `thinkfan`. The folder contains a folder `button` and a file `wakeup`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Restore BIOS to the default settings.

Press F2 repeatedly when the Lenovo logo appears on the screen, then F9 Restore to the default settings.

Here's the [Lenovo 14w](https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/syndication/mediaserverredirect/7727bed8bb9e5be9b3387a7d609da253/original.pdf) user guide if you want to try updating your BIOS to the latest version

try to adjust `lm-senors` and `fancontrol` parameters following this guide:

[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed/402310#402310)

Run :

```
fwts fan
```

to check and test fan status, or as [How do I know my fan is working in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482766/how-do-i-know-my-fan-is-working-in-ubuntu)

Finally you can check The `thinkfan` software is available in the standard ubuntu software repositories, but it does require a few steps to configure.

[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed/402310#402310)

Comment: Went through the steps but the `thinkfan` service can't start due to `/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal` not existing. I also made sure to upgrade the BIOS before uninstalling Windows.

Comment: Check these for more details on thinkfan:
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed
https://askubuntu.com/questions/481459/thinkfan-control-doesnt-use-the-fan-full-potential-when-needed
Would you try installing Ubuntu 19.04 or older versions instead of 19.10 as a temp solution to see if this fixes the situation or not, as .04 often are LTS and better-maintained Distribtutions.

Comment: LTS Ubuntu did not make a difference, manually controlling the fans with `echo level x > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` didn't work, and `thinkfan` service can't be started as it relies on `/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal` which doesn't exist :/

Comment: Do you have these settings :
From the main BIOS menu, choose ‘System Monitor’. Then go to ‘Fan Control’ option and select ‘CPU Fan Speed Control’.

• Change the control to ‘Manual’ if it is on ‘Automatic’. You can enter the percentage of the CPU fan to work according to your suitability (like 100 will be 100%).  ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, nothing fan related exists in BIOS.